# C# Revit API, CreateIndependentTag method failing to add tag to ceilings, exception at line location point

Tags: c#, tags, revit

This code attempts to add a tag to all ceilings in the ceiling views list. The ceiling view list populates and I can get the ceiling elements from the document, but it seems to be failing when trying to acquire the centre point of the ceiling element. I have googled all the blogs and I cant find a reference to tagging floors in revit either as it may be a similar scenario.

```
public IndependentTag CreateIndependentTag(Document doc)
    {
        List<View> viewList = ceilingViewCollector(doc);

        foreach (View view in viewList)
        {

            // Find all ceiling elements in the document by using category filter
            ElementCategoryFilter filter = new    ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_Ceilings);

            // Use shortcut WhereElementIsNotElementType() to find ceiling instances only
            FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
            IList<Element> CeilingList = collector.WherePasses(filter).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();


            foreach (Ceiling ceiling in CeilingList)
            {
                TaskDialog.Show("Ceiling", ceiling.Name);


                // define tag mode and tag orientation for new tag
                TagMode tagMode = TagMode.TM_ADDBY_CATEGORY;
                TagOrientation tagorn = TagOrientation.Horizontal;


                //add tag to centre of ceiling?
                LocationPoint p = ceiling.Location as LocationPoint;
                p.Point = new XYZ(0.0, p.Point.Y, p.Point.Z);
                ceilingCentre = p.Point;

                string coords = "point = " + ceilingCentre.ToString();
                TaskDialog.Show("Source room Center", coords);




                IndependentTag newTag = doc.Create.NewTag(view, ceiling, true, tagMode, tagorn, ceilingCentre);
                if (null == newTag)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Create IndependentTag Failed.");
                }
                // set leader mode free
                // otherwise leader end point move with elbow point
                newTag.LeaderEndCondition = LeaderEndCondition.Free;
                XYZ elbowPnt = ceilingCentre + new XYZ(5.0, 5.0, 0.0);
                newTag.LeaderElbow = elbowPnt;
                XYZ headerPnt = ceilingCentre + new XYZ(10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
                newTag.TagHeadPosition = headerPnt;


                return newTag;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanx for the thought @Gutblender, the code is still bugging out at the line: LocationPoint p = ceiling.Location as LocationPoint; I tried the same code on a location line and wall element and it worked fine. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Thank @Gutblender, who did the original edit. I was reviewing suggested edits in a review queue, and this one came up: there is an option to improve suggested edits, which allowed me to fix a minor indentation error that Gutblender missed.

Comment: hello, I've got two thoughts.  The first is your filtered element collector maybe needs the active view viewId.  So for example: FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc, doc.ActiveView.Id) ;  Second, you may want to get the BoundingBoxXYZ of the ceiling to calculate the midpoint of the ceiling.

Comment: ...and a third...after your 'view' foreach statement you probably want to add a check to make sure that view.ViewType != ViewType.ThreeD

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but, aren't you forgetting your X-component?

```
            //add tag to centre of ceiling?
            LocationPoint p = ceiling.Location as LocationPoint;
            p.Point = new XYZ(p.Point.X / 2, p.Point.Y / 2, p.Point.Z);
            ceilingCentre = p.Point;
```

It would seem you'd want to center this `Point` p in terms of X and Y, and keep the Z component.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I just ran across this.  Revit elements can be located by a point (most family instances), a line (walls, line based components), or a sketch (ceilings, floors, etc.).  Your code will not work because you are casting the location to a location point and it isn't a location point.

With sketches you can't cast the location to anything useful so you will need to figure out how you want to determine the center of the ceiling on your own.  The simple answer is to find the bounding box of the ceiling and calculate it's center as suggested by mtumminello.  This will work for most ceilings except if you have a large L shape or something the bounding box center may not be over the ceiling at all.  If you need this covered you would have to come up with some other algorithm to find the center point.